# How to fill page horizontally with divs without empty space at the end

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having this simple but frustrating CSS problem. I am trying to fill a page completely with divs/boxes. The problem is, that these boxes have same width all the time, therefore boxes won't fill up evenly. Let me demonstrate this:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/85rwn/).

CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

This is OK:

[image]

But if user has a smaller window size, it will go like:

[image]

This would be the best solution, resizing boxes to fit screen horizontally evenly:

[image]

What would be the best solution to make them fit whole page when window is resized? Preferably CSS-only (if possible).

Comment: Set the `width` in percent e.g. `width: 33.3%`

Comment: Do you want a fixed number per row?

Comment: @Sergio thanks for the reminder, You must have fixed number per row and then set the width in `%`

Comment: What if I don't want to have fixed amount of boxes per row? Is there any solution to that?

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen, you have to decide something :) what is the max-width before one more box per row?

Comment: @Sergio Hmm... I am really not sure yet. I think I have to think this little more, this was not as simple as I thought it could be. I think I will go with CSS media queries with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBgZ3/1/)

IMO, the solution depends om your needs. If are able to scale the images, then the 33% rule offered by others here is probably acceptable.  However, you may wish to limit how far the size can be go (min-width).  Also, this is going to totally bork your aspect ratios, which you might find unacceptable.

One alternate solution would be to have a 'viewport' div on on-top of a larger div that allows some bleed-over to minimize the 'gosh, it's only one pixel only over' effect (where you get a huge, gaping blank column.  This solution allows the cards to bleed out of the viewport a bit before forcing a new column.  And it is CSS-only.  This is the provided example.  Test it out by changing the outer container width and height ('my-outer'):

```
/* CSS */
.my-outer {
  position : relative;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  width  : 350px;
  height : 450px;
  border   : 1px solid red;
  overflow-x : hidden;
  overflow-y : auto;
}
.my-inner {
  position : relative;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  border : 1px solid green;
  width : 120%;
}
.my-card { 
  box-sizing   : border-box;
  float : left;
  margin : 10px;
  width  : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  font-size : 50px;
  line-height : 100px;
  text-align  : center;
  font-weight : 800;
  background  : #aaf;
  color       : #fff;
  border-radius : 2x;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px -2px #888;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="my-outer">
  <div class="my-inner">
   <div class="my-card">1</div>
   <div class="my-card">2</div>
   <div class="my-card">3</div>
   <div class="my-card">4</div>
   <div class="my-card">5</div>
   <div class="my-card">6</div>
   <div class="my-card">7</div>
   <div class="my-card">8</div>
   <div class="my-card">9</div>
   <div class="my-card">10</div>
   <div class="my-card">11</div>
   <div class="my-card">12</div>
   <div class="my-card">13</div>
   <div class="my-card">14</div>
   <div stlye="clear : both;"></div>
 </div>
```

Another alternate solution, which would probably provide the best user experience, would be to resize the container in steps.  This would require some JavaScript, but can be fairly easy to quite difficult to implement depending about the environment.  And yes, I have done this sort of thing before ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Cards, or boxes, should be visible all the time. I forgot to mention it, sorry. So bleed-over is really not suitable option. How about that JavaScript solution, resizing the container in steps. Do you have some kind of sample code which you could provide?

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen: You are welcome.  When you say cards or boxes should be visible at all times, what do you mean?  Is there a set number of cards (say 9) that must always be on-screen no matter the form factor?  Or do you simply mean the bleed-over solution is not acceptable?  Or something else?  Only by know the specific requirements can I help.

Comment: All cards should be on screen, none of them should be "off screen" (bleed-over). The most perfect situation would be that when cards does not fit horizontally even, cards would resize to smaller cards and fit horizontally evenly. Going to update my question.

Comment: Ah, if I understand you correctly, then that is easy.  Let's say you want a 3x3 grid of cards to fit into a given space.  The container div can be constrained to keep its aspect ratio, so the smallest (x or y) dimension is set to the width and height.  Then one could apply the say 30% card width and height and 2% margins.  If you do the math, that adds up to 100%.  The only bit that could be tricky is ensuring aspect ratio( if you need it).  That can be done with JavaScript; CSS is still spotty (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the container div `boxes` a `width` of the max amount of boxes + the margin for each box.  In your example that would be 200 * 3 + 30.  This is given that you only want three boxes per row.

Answer (score 0):

something like
html:

```
<div class="box></div>
<div class="box></div>
<div class="box></div>
<div class="box></div>
<div class="box></div>
<div class="box></div>
```

css:

```
.box{
    height: 100px;
    width: 33%;
}
```